# python3 can't convert bytes to object 'str' implicity

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-sockets

I tried to some solutions in the other questions but couldn't solve. Here is my code:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import socket
import sys
ip = "192.168.0.28"
port = 21
data = "hckn"*250
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    conn = s.connect((ip,port))
except:
    print("[-] Baglanti basarisiz")
    sys.exit()

s.recv(1024)
s.send("USER anonymous\r\n".encode('utf-8'))
s.recv(1024)
s.send("PASS anonymous\r\n".encode('utf-8'))
print("[+]Gizli baglanti saglandi")


s.recv(1024)

s.send('MKD'+data+'\r\n'.encode('ascii'))
print("Data yollandı")
s.recv(1024)
s.send('QUIT\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
s.close()

print("[+]Program yakinda hata verecek...")
```

when i erase the 'encode's and run it Python2, it works fine. But not on Python3, it says

s.send('MKD'+data+'\r\n'.encode('ascii'))

TypeError: can't convert bytes to object 'str' implicity

Comment: the default encoding in Python 3 is unicode, so you dont need to specify `coding` (the 2nd line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because parentheses are missing:

```
s.send(('MKD'+data+'\r\n').encode('ascii'))
#      ^                 ^
```

But the typical solution is to just use bytes to begin with:

```
data = b"hckn"*250
s.send(b'MKD'+data+b'\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

On that line:

```
s.send('MKD'+data+'\r\n'.encode('ascii'))
```

You need to put parantheses around the 'MKD'+data+'\r\n'. Like this:

```
s.send(('MKD'+data+'\r\n').encode('ascii'))
```